# Is it possible to set location.reload() or $state.reload() with interval value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh, reload

Well, I've got ten tab panes in my design, in a 1st tab, I used to load data with 
ng-bind(),  also have paid and unpaid invoice tabs that have popmodel to make payments.

The issues are, if I did anything with that model popup through save button, the rest of bound data from other tabs got disappeared. All I want to refresh that particular tab only.

i use this codes location.reload(); or $state.reload(); but no use its just reloads the page.

is that any solution for this.. pls share with me

```
$scope.collectbill = function() {
            $scope.billDet.amount = $scope.final_amount;
            $scope.billDet.user_id_pk = sessVar.user_id_pk;
            console.log($scope.billDet);
            $http.post('/billPay', $scope.billDet)
                .success(function(data) {
                    if (data.errorMessage != null) {
                        console.log(data.errorMessage);
                        //$scope.frmData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                    } else {
                        $location.url('/custdetails?' + $scope.invisibleMenu.listcustomer);
                        //window.location = "dashboard#/listcustomer";
                        //location.reload();
                        //$state.reload();

                        Success_Msg("bill Pay", data.msg);
                        //location.reload();
                    }
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific about your model and the view. In general it is a question of scopes. You have to check in which $scope your changes apply and on which model the changes are applied.
What do you want to achieve with location.reload()?

Comment: I still don't see why you want to reload the page. I would expect to change the status of the bill to "paid" and the view will reflect the new status immediately. So in success function you do something like $scope.bill.status = 'paid' and in the template something like:

    <div ng-if="bill.status == 'paid'>Paid</div>

Comment: i fixed it dude.. now i want to reload particular tab belong from group tabs which is in active state..  like i've 9 tabs from that, Document is one of the tab - there, user can upload their documents for verification purpose. i gave three dropdown values as fallows 1. id proof, 2, Application form, 3.Address proof, its a single file upload actually., hope you understand, i just want refresh that single tab for every upload

Comment: #tab a, #tab b,#tab c, #tab d, #tab Document and so on, if did upload 1st document, the tab got refreshed and activate from 1st tab, i need that particular tab only should get refreshed .. is it possible???

Comment: You should not need to refresh anything in angular. Just change the model to your needs and the tab should be updated automatically